# available roomcombinations with nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

I have to build a function which calculates the room options that are available for a guest.
For example; the guest has chosen 2 rooms in his inquiry, 1 room for ‘two adults’ and 1 room for ‘2 adults and a child’.
After a couple of calculations there will be 2 arrays. 1 array contains the possible rooms (searched per room inquiry) and 1 array has the availability (how many rooms are available of this room-type in the hotel).

The first array with the possible rooms will for example look like this:

```
$rooms = array
  (
  'adultsroom' => array(15,501,539,18),
  'familyroom' => array(15,501,539)
  );

echo '<pre>'; print_r($rooms); echo '</pre>';
```

Where nested array [0] stands for the first searched room inquiry (2 adults) and nested array [1] for the second searched room inquiry (2 adults and a 3 year old child).

So for the first room inquiry the possible room_id’s are '15', '501', '539' en '18'.

The second array with the availability will for example look like this:
(room_id’s that are mentioned in the first array will always appear in the availability array)

```
$roomsavailable = array
    (
    '15' => 1,
    '501' => 2,
    '539' => 1,
    '18' => 4
    );

echo '<pre>'; print_r($roomsavailable); echo '</pre>';
```

This array indicates that for the chosen arrival date there are 4 rooms available of room_id ‘18’.

The function called 'get_room_combinations' receives these array’s and calculates all the possible room combinations.

The array output will look in this case like this (where [0] in the nested array (2nd
level array) stands for the first room inquiry and [1] for the second room inquiry):

```
function get_room_combinations(array $data, array &$all = array(), array $group = array(), $value = null, $i = 0)
{
    $keys = array_keys($data);
    if (isset($value) === true) {
        array_push($group, $value);
    }

    if ($i >= count($data)) {
        array_push($all, $group);
    } else {
        $currentKey     = $keys[$i];
        $currentElement = $data[$currentKey];
        foreach ($currentElement as $val) {
            get_room_combinations($data, $all, $group, $val, $i + 1);
        }
    }

    return $all;
}

$data = array(
    array('15', '501', '539', '18'),
    array('15', '501', '539'),
);

$combos = get_room_combinations($data);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($combos); echo '</pre>';
```

I have a piece of code which render one array with 12 combinations. It didn't look at the availability at the moment.

Who can help me here with this script to render one array with the 10 available combinations?

Array
(

[0] => Array
 (
 [0] => 15
 [1] => 501
 )

[1] => Array
 (
 [0] => 15
 [1] => 539
 )

[2] => Array
 (
 [0] => 501
 [1] => 15
 )

[3] => Array
 (
 [0] => 501
 [1] => 501
 )

[4] => Array
 (
 [0] => 501
 [1] => 539
 )

[5] => Array
 (
 [0] => 539
 [1] => 15
 )

[6] => Array
 (
 [0] => 539
 [1] => 501
 )

[7] => Array
 (
 [0] => 18
 [1] => 15
 )

[8] => Array
 (
 [0] => 18
 [1] => 501
 )

[9] => Array
 (
 [0] => 18
 [1] => 539
 )
);

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If this is a homework question, please make sure to tag it as such.

Comment: @PeterDeWeese The homework tag was deprecated 2 years ago.

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate the language this question is about.

Comment: Please read about asking questions by following the help center link at the help button in the top banner. Including [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).